# Finding the Equation of the Circle with a given line and tangent x axis

Tags: linear-algebra, analytic-geometry

So my Professor ask us to solve a problem finding the equation of the circle with only a given

"Tangent to the x-axis with center on x + 4y = 5"

I'm confused in the part how do I find the center point in a line without a given endpoints of the line?

What I think about the problem is that the center would be along the given line and the x intercept would be the point where the circle touches

Edit:
after analyzing how it could be done. I found out that it really isn't a unique circle, the center and the x axis can be adjusted to match the given.

[This is the first graph of equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCESR.png)

[This is another one that was adjusted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYR4o.png)

My problem now is how do I create an differential equation of family of circles that would only satisfy the given problem.

Sorry I'm new, thank you for everyone's kind response

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Could you please be more specific, in the sense that, do you want a full solution or a hint? Also, could you please be more specific as to what you are confused about.

Comment: Thank you sorry I'm new. If possible I want a full solution so I could understand why and how to use the solution to apply it other similar problems. I don't know how to be specific in this problem our professor asked to find the equation of circle using the given "Tangent to the x-axis with center on x +4y = 5"

Comment: I have tried to give you some hint, seeing your difficulty. Please use it fully.

Comment: @Narasimham maybe delete this comment until you fix your now deleted answer.

Comment: There are a family of such circles, not just one. Start with any center point on the line other than where the line meets the $x$ axis, then drop a perpendicular from that point to the $x$ axis to get the radius.

Comment: @coffeemath Thank you I would try this. Is there a chance that I would not find a unique circle?

Comment: You will not find a unique circle, because as I noted the center can be at any of the (infinitely many) points on the given line other than where the line crosses the x axis. [And two circles with different centers are different circles.] Perhaps you omitted some other condition of your professor's problem which would make it unique. On the other hand maybe your professor wants you to find them all, or even satisfied if you find one of them.

Comment: @coffeemath Thank you. I was really confused and in doubt at first because every problems that I encountered so far were unique circles but this one is different. I realize that there's no constant given so I think you're right.

Comment: If you solved it, then this site encourages users to "answer" their own questions.

Comment: I'd like to see that graph. Because once you have one case that works, one can imagine moving the center along the line, at the same time changing the radius, so as to keep the circle tangent to the x axis.

Comment: I noticed you deleted your comment about having graphed it and getting a unique circle. Please don't delete comments that someone responds to--- it makes the response unmotivated.

Comment: Oh sorry, I meant to edit not delete. How do I send the graph here? It seems that there's a unique circle for the given.

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to put a graph here. But you can add to your question the information about where the center of your circle is (coordinates) and what its radius is.

Comment: Your two graphs you have inserted in the question are both satisfying requirements, and they show what I mean about the family of equations. Your question still doesn't mention  you need a differential equation for the family of circles. That information should be put in the question if it was what your professor wanted you to find.

Comment: @coffeemath yeah that too is a problem, I don't know what does my professor want us to do. I'm guessing anything goes as long the question can be answered.

Comment: @Confundo I highly suggest you ask your professor what he wants you to do. Are you taking a differential equations course from the professor? If so and you ask the professor and get an answer what you are to find, and if it is a differential equation for the circles, I have a way which i can answer. But I don't want to go to the trouble of doing so unless that's definitely what your professor wants you to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are obviously *not a unique one* but multiple ( an infinite set) circle solutions.

[image]

They can be set by a variable center point given on the given parametrized straight line

$$ (x_C,y_C)=(t, \frac{5-t}{4})$$

You can find them all

$$ (x-x_C)^2+(y-y_C)^2= y_C^2.$$

Find ***the*** equation of Circle in the question misleads.

Comment: Is the blue line supposed to be $x+4y=5$? [It doen't look like your blue line has that equation.]

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my graphing error. Hope now it all stands corrected .